# How To Use [Authorize] properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

I have two groups of users, one group of people are being hired, and one group of people are hiring.

I would like to restrict access to certain pages for each group of users, but when I use [Authorize] in the controller, it allows access to any signed in user without differentiating which group they are from?

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Signin(string username, string password)
        {
            var mgr = new Cleaners.Models.UserManager(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog='Cleaning Lady';Integrated Security=True");
            var user = mgr.GetUser(username, password);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return View(new UserViewModel { Name = username });
            }

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, true);
            UserViewModel.IsAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            return RedirectToAction("Private");
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Private()
        {
            return View();

        }
```

Is there any way to restrict access to "private" to users that were verified through this controller?

Comment: You can use identity roles and authorize based on them.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm giving a simple example:

```
    [Authorize(Roles="Contractor")]
    public ActionResult Private()
    {
        return View();

    }
```

This will check whether the current user/identity has a Role named Contractor.

I'd suggest you to read [this article](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc) to understand the basics of it.

Comment: In addition to this, you can create your own custom Authorize Attribute that extends the Authorize class to check on permissions however you want. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357%28v=vs.91%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Or we could implement `IUserStore` by ourselves, and implement custom logic. I had a situation users could belong to groups, which had profiles, and profiles had Roles (very granular). This is nice because if you also use Web Api, you don't have to implement both `Authorize`s (not a problem in Core 1.0 anymore).

Comment: Thanks! @Alisson can you explain to me briefly how to store in the database their role,  and how to pull that information in order to give them access? Thanks!

Comment: Asp.net Identity, will create a `Roles` table, where you should insert the roles of your app (manually or in seed method, as it'd be done in EF), in your case, you have two. There is also an `AspNetUsers` table where users are stored, and another table for `AspNetUserRoles`, where you configure what users have what roles. Once this is set up, Authorize will work properly. I suggest you read about asp.net Identity and learn about it, it's not hard. I think SO is not the right place to teach how to do things, is more to solve some problem you've got, otherwise I could give more details.